# How to make this JavaScript function with two nested functions return the correct string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement JavaScript tool for generating a random video from specific channel from youtube, I coded everything and it works fine in the console, however I cannot save the value in variable and to display the video later on my website. Is it possible to make the value of x (defined on the end of the pasted code) have the value of youtubeUrl

```
function getVideo() {
    var channelId = "";
    var apiKey = "";
    var videosUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=" + channelId + "&maxResults=50&key=" + apiKey;

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", videosUrl, true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
            var videos = json.items;

            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (videos.length + 1));
            var randomVideo = videos[randomNumber];

            var videoId = randomVideo.id.videoId;
            var videoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&key=" + apiKey;

            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("GET", videoUrl, true);
            ajax.send();

            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    var singleVideo = json.items[0].id;
                    var youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + singleVideo;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
let x = getVideo(); // how to make it such that x has the value of youtubeUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the content of your function inside a new Promise constructor and resolve it with the youtubeUrl:

```js
function getVideo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var channelId = "";
      var apiKey = "";
      var videosUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=" + channelId + "&maxResults=50&key=" + apiKey;

      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajax.open("GET", videosUrl, true);
      ajax.send();

      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
              var videos = json.items;

              var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (videos.length + 1));
              var randomVideo = videos[randomNumber];

              var videoId = randomVideo.id.videoId;
              var videoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&key=" + apiKey;

              var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
              ajax.open("GET", videoUrl, true);
              ajax.send();

              ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                      var singleVideo = json.items[0].id;
                      var youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + singleVideo;
                     resolve(youtubeUrl);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
let x = await getVideo();
```

Comment: I tried using this method and it gives me SyntaxError: await is only defined in async functions

Comment: The call to the method getVideo() should be done either inside an async function, or you have to use this syntax: `getVideo().then(url => console.log(url))`